# Using distinct with Column Value within Constructor Query of HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to retrieve the records based on the distinct Lab Number from the database.
The problem i have is there are multiple labs taken by patient and multiple lab numbers are stored in the joined tables.
Here is my query:

```
 Select distinct new org.laborders.dto.LabOrderDTO(ps.labNumber,ps.patientServiceId,
 ps,patientName,pso.patientServiceOrderId,pso.totalAmount) 
 from patientServices ps join patientServicesOrder pso
```

I want to retrieve unique records on **ps.labNumber**.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like this -

```
Select distinct new  org.laborders.dto.LabOrderDTO(ps.labNumber,ps.patientServiceId,
ps,patientName,pso.patientServiceOrderId,pso.totalAmount) 
from patientServices ps join patientServicesOrder pso
```

Look i have placed the keyword distinct first and then new package.class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with "DISTINCT + Constructor" in @Query.
The solution i found was rewriting the query like this:

```
Select new org.laborders.dto.LabOrderDTO(ps.labNumber,ps.patientServiceId,
 ps,patientName,pso.patientServiceOrderId,pso.totalAmount) 
 from patientServices ps join patientServicesOrder pso
GROUP BY ps.labNumber,ps.patientServiceId,
 ps,patientName,pso.patientServiceOrderId,pso.totalAmount
```

Using GROUP BY with all your select-columns has the same effect as using DISTINCT.

I am using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate.